# table graphite.account_profile does not exist

Tags: graphite

I have installed Graphite on Ubuntu 18.04 using apt-get
I have also installed MySQL, created a database as well as a user in it
I have run graphite-manage migrate auth to migrate the database models

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
response = self._get_response(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite/composer/views.py", line 35, in composer
profile = getProfile(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite/user_util.py", line 25, in getProfile
return default_profile()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite/user_util.py", line 44, in default_profile
profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 464, in get_or_create
return self.get(**lookup), False
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 374, in get
num = len(clone)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 232, in len
self._fetch_all()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in iter
results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 899, in execute_sql
raise original_exception
ProgrammingError: (1146, u"Table 'graphite.account_profile' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run manage.py migrate but no accout related tables created in graphite.db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426835/run-manage-py-migrate-but-no-accout-related-tables-created-in-graphite-db)

Answer (score 0):

Just execute:

**graphite-manage migrate --run-syncdb**

And graphite-migrate will create account_profile and other tables for you.